# Using Moment.js to find a specific day of the current week's date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, momentjs

**Finding the date of a specific day of the current week with Moment.js**

---

There are lots of ways to manipulate dates in javascript. I've been looking for the simplest, easiest way to do so without long, ugly code, so someone showed me [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/).

I want to use the current date to discover the date of a specific day of the current week with this library. My attempt so far involves taking the difference between the current day number(days 0-6) and checking how many days are between it and monday(day 1), which is not right at all.

[Here's my fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/5HSFN/1/)

Here's my code:

```
var now = moment();

var day = now.day();

var week = [['sunday',0],['monday',1],['tuesday',2],['wednesday',3],['thursday',4],['friday',5],['saturday',6]];

var monday = moment().day(-(week[1][1] - day));//today minus the difference between monday and today

$("#console").text(monday);

//I need to know the date of the current week's monday
//I need to know the date of the current week's friday
```

How can I do this? My method may be a terrible way to get this done, or it might be somewhat close. I do, however want the solution to be neat, small, dynamic, and simple, as all code should be.

I'd prefer not to use native JS date functionality which produces ugly, messy code in every situation that I've seen.

Comment: As far as the `week` array goes, I felt as if I needed more than just an array of the numbers 1-6, and that the names might be helpful if included.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

this week's sunday

```
moment().startOf('week')
```

this week's monday

```
moment().startOf('isoweek')
```

this week's saturday

```
moment().endOf('week')
```

difference between the current day to sunday

```
moment().diff(moment().startOf('week'),'days')
```

this week's wedesday

```
moment().startOf('week').add('days', 3)
```

Comment: Note that `moment().add('days', 3)` has been depricated in the latest version of moment. It should now be `moment().add(3, 'days')`

Comment: can we find startOf of a particular year ?

Comment: for me. ```moment(date).endOf('week')``` worked for sunday

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a little late to the party, but here's the proper way to do this, as in the [documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/).

```
moment().day(1); // Monday in the current week
```

Also if in your locale it happens that the week starts with Monday and you wish to get a locally aware result, you can use `moment().weekday(0)`. [Here's the documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/weekday/) for the `moment().weekday(dayNumber)` method.

Answer (score 2):

It's not longer possible to use just a string (e. g. 'isoweek'), we need to use it like this:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { unitOfTime } from 'moment';

moment().startOf('isoweek' as unitOfTime.StartOf);
```

Comment: I think this is if you are using typescript, not because its no longer possible.