# How to find the dates of coming saturday and sunday from today's date in typescript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have set today's date in code as follows,

```
 public fromDate: Date = new Date();
```

How can i find the dates of coming saturday and sunday, mean this weekend dates from the above?

i can try by adding number of days from the current day. but is there a better solution?

Comment: momentjs can help you with this task, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22599706/2435473)

Comment: Check this - http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/33527/find-next-occurring-friday-or-any-dayofweek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using an external library, you can use `moment`'s [`day`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/day/) function.

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
const fromDate = moment();
const nextSunday = fromDate.day(7);
console.log(nextSunday.calendar());
```