# Get next week's start and end date using pure javascript

Tags: javascript, date, typescript

I was using moment.js to calculate the next week start date and end date. but right now i have removed it because of some minification issue.

I am able to get this week's start and end date as follows,

```
var today = new Date; 
var first = today.getDate() - today.getDay(); 
(this.fromDate = new Date(today.setDate(first)));
(this.toDate  = new Date(today.setDate(last)));
```

how to find next week start and end date?

Comment: Could you use the code in my answer to your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158971/how-to-find-the-dates-of-coming-saturday-and-sunday-from-todays-date-in-typescr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sum 7 days to the start of this week to get the start of the next week; to get the end of the week add 6 days to the start of the week.

```js
var date = new Date;
var nextWeekStart = date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 7;
var nextWeekFrom = new Date(date.setDate(nextWeekStart));
var nextWeekEnd = date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6;
var nextWeekTo = new Date(date.setDate(nextWeekEnd));

console.log('nextWeekFrom: ' + nextWeekFrom.toString())
console.log('nextWeekTo  : ' + nextWeekTo.toString())
```

Comment: This code gives an incorrect result for the end of next week. The line `var nextWeekEnd = ...` should be after `var nextWeekFrom = ...` as that line modifies *date*.

Comment: @RobG you are right. i messed up after editing the last time. thanks again

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using `getFullYear()`,`getMonth()` and `getDate()` methods.

```js
function getWeekBegin() {
   var now = new Date();
   var next = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()+(7 - now.getDay()));
   return next;
}
var firstDay = getWeekBegin();
console.log("First day: "+firstDay);
var lastDay=firstDay.setDate(firstDay.getDate() + 6);
console.log("Last day: "+new Date(lastDay));
```

Comment: lastDay is not of date type

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% what your after, but if you modify this a little you should be able to figure out how

```
function test() {
    var today = new Date; 
    alert(getMonday(today));
}
function getMonday( date ) {
    date.setHours((24*7));
    var day = date.getDay() || 7;  
    if( day !== 1 ) 
        date.setHours(-24 * (day - 1)); 
    return date;
}
```

Just edited the answer, this should get you next mondays date

Comment: You shouldn't add days by adding hours as not all days are 24 hours long due to daylight saving changes.

Answer (score 0):

The following simplifies the code and provides some explanation. The *setDate* method modifies the date and returns the new time value, so it can be used to modify a date and create a copy in one go.

```js
// Get current date
var d = new Date();

// Set to next Sunday and copy
var startOfWeek = new Date(d.setDate(d.getDate() + 7 - d.getDay()));

// Set to the following Saturday
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 6);

console.log('Start of week: ' + startOfWeek.toString());
console.log('End of week  : ' + d.toString());

// The following shows the dates formatted and in the host default language
// Support for toLocaleString options may be lacking though
var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
console.log('Start of week: ' + startOfWeek.toLocaleString(undefined, options));
console.log('End of week  : ' + d.toLocaleString(undefined, options));
```