# How do I add all missing days in my object in the current week and the week after in React Native?

Tags: arrays, date, object, react-native

I have an events Object. As you can see below, the object always has the current day and some other days. In the current version of the object shown underneath, the object has 2 days as keys. The first day key is **2018-01-26** and the second is **2018-01-28**. I want to check and add keys for all days which are not in the object but are in the current week. Those keys will have an empty array as value. How do I do that ? Thanks

```
{
  "2018-01-26": Array [
    Object {
      "allDay": false,
      "color": "#1abc9c",
      "height": 150,
      "location": "University of Illinois at Urbna-Champaign",
      "name": "Bsbshsjhs",
      "startDate": "2018-01-26",
      "startTime": "07:25 am",
      "stopDate": "2018-01-26",
      "stopTime": "08:25 am",
    },
    Object {
      "allDay": false,
      "color": "#1abc9c",
      "height": 150,
      "location": "University of Illinois at Urbna-Champaign",
      "name": "Hdhrhhfj",
      "startDate": "2018-01-26",
      "startTime": "09:19 am",
      "stopDate": "2018-01-26",
      "stopTime": "10:19 am",
    },
    Object {
      "allDay": false,
      "color": "#1abc9c",
      "height": 150,
      "location": "University of Illinois at Urbna-Champaign",
      "name": "Mmmmmmm",
      "startDate": "2018-01-26",
      "startTime": "09:23 am",
      "stopDate": "2018-01-26",
      "stopTime": "10:23 am",
    },
    Object {
      "allDay": false,
      "color": "#1abc9c",
      "height": 150,
      "location": "University of Illinois at Urbna-Champaign",
      "name": "Gghhh",
      "startDate": "2018-01-26",
      "startTime": "10:41 am",
      "stopDate": "2018-01-26",
      "stopTime": "11:41 am",
    },
  ],
  "2018-01-28": Array [],
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code will check if date exists, If not add an empty array.

```
if (!eventObj[date]) {
  eventObj[date] = []
}
```

Comment: cool. The hard part, which is bugging me is how to get all the dates of the current week so I have a reference to check

Comment: You could use a library like moment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22599301/using-moment-js-to-find-a-specific-day-of-the-current-weeks-date